# EF Core 3.0: duplicate insert with huge amount of data

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core with .NET Core 3.0. I am facing a very weird case. I am transferring data from SQLite to SQL Server.

```
using (var context1 = new Context1())
using (var context2 = new Context2())
{
    foreach(var tran in context1.Transactions.Distinct())
    {
        var trans = new Model{
            PersonID = tran.PersonID,
            CreatedDate = tran.TranDate,
            TranDate = tran.TranDate,
            CreatedBy = tran.CreatedBy
        };
        context2.Transactions.Add(trans);

    }

    int cc = context2.SaveChanges();
    int count1 = context1.Transactions.Count();
    int count2 = context2.Transactions.Count();
}
```

The problem is when inserting a small bulk of data (1,000 rows), data integrity is fine, but when inserting 200,000 records at once, the data becomes duplicated but the number of records that should be inserted is correct.

Also I noticed the duplicates happen in different cycles as their IDs are not in sequence and the inserts occur randomly!

```
ID      TranDate                   PersonID CreatedBy CreatedDate 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
513842  2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419 93596   NULL    2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419 
516055  2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419 93596   NULL    2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419 
516342  2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419 93596   NULL    2019-06-17 10:29:11.3368419
```

UPDATE:
just to confirm the duplicates

SQLite Data

[image]

SqlServer:

[image]

Update2:

```
Console.WriteLine(context1.Transactions.OrderBy(t => t.TranDate).GroupBy(t => t.TranDate).Count());
```

> 194735

However;

```
foreach(var tran in context1.Transactions.OrderBy(t => t.TranDate).AsEnumerable().GroupBy( x => x.TranDate).Select(g => g.First()))
```

the total number transfered to SqlServer is

[image]

Comment: RE: 'at once' Are you running more than one task?

Comment: Its strange why you call distinct but anyway try to use orderBy  context1.Transactions.OrderBy(t=>t.Id)

Comment: Why are you doing `Distinct` on the source data? Are there duplicates there?

Comment: @tymtam I think they try to remove duplicates :)

Comment: there is no duplicate in the data, but I wanted to confirm

Comment: @AbdulkarimKanaan try to apply order i beleive that its sq-lite can return you data which are sorted in random way

Comment: a) COUNT(*) against the source returns how many rows? COUNT(*) against the target returns how many rows?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills count returns exactly same number for both

Comment: Are you cleaning the target db before re-runing the code?

Comment: @tymtam absolutely!

Comment: Hm. This is the same row repeated 3 times on separate runs, isn't it?

Comment: What's the `SQLite Data` query you used to show 1 row?

Comment: You need to narrow down the cause. Stop writing to SQL Server - instead write to a file. Does the file have duplicates?

Comment: Please try the thing I suggested. We need to clarify whether your bug is in the **reading** or the **writing**.

Comment: BTW. 194,735 is consistent with ids growing from 500000, to 700,000 between two runs.

Comment: yes it is consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be related to the duplication of db context. Since the both db structures are same almost, I duplicated the exiting db context and changed the connection strings. it must be something inside still refering to each other?! I don't know. the problem appeard only after three thousands entries.

However, what I did to solve the issue was I deleted all db context related files including the models and regenrate new ones using `scaffold` commands for each database

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=data.db" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite --output-dir Models

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connectionstring" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models
```

the result I did not have duplicates in the data but they were not inserted in order and it seems the normal behavior of EF.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `Distinct()` doesn't do do what you think it does.

I suspect that the original table has 'duplicates' with different ids.

I suggest you use `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`:

```
context1.Transactions
    .GroupBy( x => 
       new { x.PersonID,
             x.TranDate,
             x.CreatedBy} )
     .Select( g=> g.First());
```

Comment: they dont have problem with duplicates sqlite data are fine

Comment: Why is the OP using `Distinct` then?

Comment: simply because they believe that it will help, but as they mentioned in comments they dont have any issues with duplication of data in sql, look at my answer problem should be in sorting.

Comment: thanks @tymtam but didn't work. Seems Sqlite driver problem, but not sure yet.

Answer (score -1):

A bulk insert is better suited when the number of rows is in the 200,000 range.

If you do not care about transactional integrity, you could insert them in chunks of 1,000 or 5,000 rows at a time.